# Como melhorar meu código (muitos If's e else's)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tenho uma função para buscar um json localmente e alterar os dados de algumas fields.
porém tenhoq ue fazer o teste se o campo está com o codigo de status e dependendo eu altero com o valor correto para visualização no frontend.

segue exemplo:

```
  $http.get("http://localteste:18888/tess").success(function (dados) {


         local_locations = $.map(dados, function (dev) {
            //Verifica Status da Bateria

            if (dev.status) {
                if (dev.status <= 10)
                    dev.status= "Muito Baixo";
               else if (dev.status<= 25)
                    dev.status = "Baixo";;
               else if ((dev.status== 50) || (dev.status>= 25))
                    dev.status= "Medio";;
              else  if ((dev.status== 75) || (dev.status>= 50))
                    dev.status= "Alto";;
               else if ((dev.status== 100) || (dev.status> 75))
                    dev.batUseBattery = "Muito alto";
       }
 });
```

Seria mais ou menos isso, porém há muitos testes como esse.
Como eu poderia melhorar?

Comment: Qual o objetivo de reduzir o número de if?
É apenas por causa da leitura? Em relação a complexidade algorítmica não existe qualquer problema.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Uma das coisas que eu não entendi no seu código é o motivo de estar usando duas comparações por `if`. Supostamente basta um teste em cada, pois se qualquer uma das comparações for verdadeira, você não chegará no else if seguinte (como já dito na resposta do @Wakim):

```
// O if externo pode ser removido se você tem certeza de ser numerico
   if (dev.status <= 10) {
      dev.batUseBattery = "Muito Baixo";
   } else if (dev.status <= 25) {
      dev.batUseBattery = "Baixo";
   } else if (dev.status <= 50) {
      dev.batUseBattery = "Medio";
   } else if (dev.status <= 75) {
      dev.batUseBattery = "Alto";
   } else { // não precisa comparar nada aqui, afinal ja é maior que 75
      dev.batUseBattery = "Muito alto";
   }
```

Outra alternativa, caso tenha muitos valores, é o uso de um *loop* e um *array* para testar as faixas (mas na quantidade de opções do seu exemplo, eu ficaria com `if...else` mesmo).

```
dev.batUseBattery = "Muito baixo";
var niveis = [
    [10,'Baixo'], // Maior que 10 é "Baixo"
    [25,'Medio'], // Maior que 25 é "Medio" etc...
    [50,'Alto'],
    [75,'Muito alto'],
];
for (var i = 0; i < niveis.length; i++) {
   if( dev.Status > niveis[i][0] ) {
       dev.batUseBattery = niveis[i][1];
   }
}
```

Faça seus testes no **[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bacco/6a95ac81/)**.

Comment: Bem legal essa segunda forma, +1.

Comment: @Wakim a primeira, que é "quase um clone" da sua (devidamente "upada"), eu ainda acho melhor pra poucas opções, a segunda eu deixei pensando em um caso que a pessoa tivesse uma situação com bem mais opções.

Comment: eu cheguei a pensar em fazer um mapa para indexar com o `status` (se não tivesse o intervalo de 10 era simples), mas o seu é bem mais legível.

Comment: Caraca. Mandou bem! A segunda opção ficaria inviável implantar agora. Mas muito obrigado pela observação! :D

Comment: Só por curiosidade, qual a relação de custo benefício entre as duas opções? O que seria menos "custoso" para o browser realizar, os IFs ou o FOR com IF interno + ARRAY ?

Comment: @Fernando Esse tipo de coisa vai depender muito da implementação do browser, para saber ao certo somente um benchmark mesmo. Provavelmente o loop vai ter um consumo maior, pois executa a mesma quantidade de `if`s do código de cima e mais o _loop_. Mas lembre-se que estamos falando de diferenças tão desprezíveis neste caso, que compensa pensar mais na legibilidade do que no excesso de otimização.

Comment: Exato, eu acredito ser mais legível os IFs do que um for. Principalmente para manutenção de regras. Outra coisa @Bacco, não funciona para Nível "Baixo"...
Experimente colocar Status = 9 no seu JS Fiddle...

Comment: @Fernando baixo é de 11 a 25, de acordo com o código original do autor. Eu mudei a ordem do if para o caso dele precisar verificar se batUseBattery é null (aí ele pode por um IF para nem entrar no loop). O array é testado para maior que 10, maior que 25 etc. De qualquer forma, levando em conta sua consideração, editei e pus comments no código para isto ficar mais claro.

Comment: Equívoco meu... interpretei a leitura do array como associação entre valores e níveis. Tens razão @Bacco.

Comment: @Fernando de qq forma eu editei e pus comments no código explicando, pq de fato o critério que eu usei poderia induzir a erro.

Comment: Pra ver como legibilidade é subjetivo, eu acho a técnica de *lookup* mais legível que o salsichão de `if`, pelo menos se tiver opções suficientes para compensar :)

Answer (score 4):

Você pode reduzir esses `if's` verificando apenas o limite superior do intervalo, e fazendo proveito da ordem em que as condições são avaliadas para encaixar o valor no intervalo correto.

Cuidado porque se `dev.status` for `0`, ele não vai classificar corretamente.

```
if ((typeof dev.status) !== 'undefined') {
    if (dev.status <= 10)
        dev.batUseBattery= "Muito Baixo";
    else if (dev.status <= 25)
        dev.batUseBattery = "Baixo";
    else if (dev.status <= 50)
        dev.batUseBattery= "Medio";
    else  if (dev.status <= 75)
        dev.batUseBattery= "Alto";
    else if (dev.status <= 100)
        dev.batUseBattery = "Muito alto";
}
```

Fiz um [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gxr8fxvc/) para que possa ver o resultado.

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que não tem muito o que fazer.
Pode retirar os ELSEs e fazer intervalos nos IFs mas sinceramente não vejo nenhum ganho de organização ou otimização.

```
if ((typeof dev.status) !== 'undefined') {
  if (dev.status <= 10)
    dev.batUseBattery= "Muito Baixo";
  if (dev.status > 10 && dev.status <= 25)
    dev.batUseBattery = "Baixo";
  if (dev.status > 25 && dev.status <= 50)
    dev.batUseBattery= "Medio";
  if (dev.status > 50 && dev.status <= 75)
    dev.batUseBattery= "Alto";
  if (dev.status > 75)
    dev.batUseBattery = "Muito alto";
}
```

Com switch não dá porque são intervalos e não valores exatos.